# How do I type on a Bézier curve?

Tags: text-object

How can I get an effect like this?

[image]

This is what I have right now:

[image]

I'm trying to make the words follow the line so I can curve sentences downward.

Credits: https://www.behance.net/gallery/60396931/BLACK-SERIES-1-POSTER-COLLECTION

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it this way:

- Create a spiral with <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve* > *Curve Spirals* > *Archemedian* (maybe it needs the Extra Objects addon?).
- Play with the parameters on the bottom of the *T* panel (left of the 3D View), give it a *Height* value.
- Put the origin of the spiral on its bottom. Check the direction so that it goes up.
- Keep the spiral selected and in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape* > *Twisting* dropdown menu > choose *Z-up*, so that the text will stand up.
- Create your text with <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> > *Text* and type what you want in *Edit* mode.
- Convert your text to mesh with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh From Curve*.
- Put the text at the same point as the spiral origin.
- Give your text an *Array* modifier.
- Give your text a *Curve* modifier with the Spiral as *Object*.
- Now play with the *Array Count*, with the *Array Relative Offset*, with the *Curve Deformation Axis*, and with the text object rotation, until the text correctly follows the spiral.
- Maybe your text mesh will need some work and additional edge loops so that it bends correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

All it is, is a curve modifier, really.

Assign the modifier to the text, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> on the curve points in edit mode to change the twist, and make the text stand up.

If you want to give all the points on the curve the same twist.. first set the twist of all points to 0 in the Transform Panel, and in a new operation, raise it to the required value.